# Variables undefined when requiring view by parent controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, undefined, controllers

I'm working with controllers and views (no framework) and have a problem with requiring a view from a parent Controller, which causes variables to be undefined.

There's a main Controller with a view function , which does requiring of views.

```
class Controller {
    public function view($view, $data =[]){                  
    require_once './app/views/' . $view . '.php';
}
```

Then there's a User controller extending the Controller, with a method, "mypage" which loads stuff in variables and requires a view. (You can access Mypage in the URL if logged in).

```
class User extends Controller{
    public function mypage(){
        $userdetails = $this->getuserdetails();                  
        $userstatus = $this->getstatus();                     
        $messages = new Messages();                            
        $showmessages = $messages->showMessages();            
        $friends = new Friends();                            
        $outrequests = $friends->outRequests();             
        $increquests = $friends->incRequests();          
        $friendsstatuses = $friends->friendsstatuses();
        $getfriends = $friends->friends();
        $this->view('mypage');
        }
 }
```

The line **$this->view('mypage');** starts the view method in the parent Controller which requires the mypage view (mypage.php), where the variables are used. The probem is that all variables become undefined in mypage.php.

If I exchange that line with

```
require_once "./app/views/mypage.php";
```

, then it works. So why do I lose the variables when requiring from the Controller, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you requiring the class Controller in class User page?

Comment: In User class , I have an autoloader : spl_autoload_register(function($class) {                
    require_once "./app/controllers/" . ($class) . ".php";
});

Answer (score 2):

Wild guess, but I think that this is a scope issue:

You're defining your variables in the `mypage()` function, so those variables only live in the scope of this function. 
Calling `$this->view(...)` just calls another method which has its own scope (where your variables don't exist).

Whereas when you call directly the `require_once(...)`, your included view script inherit variables already defined in the current scope.

Comment: I suppose it's a scope issue, but how would I make it work? Or is it unnessary to have the Controller requiring the views?

Comment: @Galivan : You need to find a way to pass your values to the view script. For example you could use an associative array or stdClass object in your Controller where keys would be variables name (and values... the values) and pass it to the `$this->view(...)` method as second parameter. Then in the `view()` function and use the [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function. Don't forget to add proper escaping too !

Comment: Ok, I see! But it seems to be an unnecessary detour. I just wanted to make things more effective, and I'm still learning. Maybe I will just use "require" from the user class.

Comment: @Galivan : If you're trying to explore the MVC pattern, you'll have to create something that represent your View. That can be a View object that will hold the values you need to display. See this example I found : http://salopek.eu/content/28/create-a-simple-php-mvc-framework

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm currently not using a "model" (although I have one) , maybe that's the missing piece. I have looked at many tutorials, but haven't seen many examples dealing with the process of displaying a webpage along with some variables. But I'll take a look at the link.